# How to prevent only closing of bootstrap modal on backspace keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Form in bootstrap Modal. I have disabled the backspace button when bootstrap modal is open by this code

```
$('body').keydown(function (e) {
        if ($('#myModal').is(':visible')) {
            if (e.keyCode == 8) { 
                return false;
            }
        }
});
```

In bootstrap modal form I have textbox, textarea I need backspace button there.
I am not able to use the backspace button in textbox which is in the bootstrap modal form

Comment: Why have you _have disabled the backspace button when bootstrap modal is open_?

Comment: because while pressing backpace it closes bootstrap modal when bootstrap modal is open

Comment: so the modal still closes even when focus is on text box

Comment: No. when modal is open backspace button is disabled right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
$('body').keydown(function (e) {
    if ($('#myModal').is(':visible')) {
        var rx = /INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/i;
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            if(!rx.test(e.target.tagName) || e.target.disabled || e.target.readOnly ){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: stop! backspace button does'n close modal. What do you need to do? Little more information please.